# Deploying a production Node.js server

Tags: javascript, deployment, node.js, production-environment

I've written a Node.js app, I'm looking to get it running on one of our production machines. This seems like a pretty common request yet I can't find an adequate solution. Is there not established solutions for deploying production Node.js apps?

The app is simple (<100 LOC), but needs to be very efficient, reliable and could run continuously for years without restarting. It's going to be run on a large site, with dozens of connections/second. (the app is not used as a webserver, it only has a JSON API)

Here are the approaches I've considered but I'm still not sure about:

**Using a framework (eg. Express)**

Because the app needs to be high performance and is so simple, adding bloat in the form of a framework is something I want to avoid.

**Starting the server with `nohup`**

The main problem here is with exception handling, we (obviously) don't want the entire server to crash because of an exception. From what I understand, wrapping the entire app in a `try {} catch {}` loop won't help because the Javascript interpreter is left in an unpredictable state after an exception. Is that correct?

**Using something like Forever**

I've installed Forever in a FreeBSD machine of ours and it was very buggy. It ended up spawning endless processes that couldn't be killed from Forever. I had to run `kill -9` to get my machine back and I don't feel too confident about running a production app on Forever. It also seems that Upstart (similar tool, but more generic) won't run on FreeBSD.

**Hosted solutions (eg. Heroku, Rackspace, Amazon EC2, etc.)**

This is probably the simplest solution, but we already have a the serious hardware for the rest of our webservers. For financial considerations, it doesn't make sense.

Surely there must be some established solution to this? Am I missing something?

Comment: upstart is a replacement for sysvinit on freebsd.

Comment: For the 2014 crowd reading this SO. `Forever` shouldn't be discounted because it failed in this one case over two years and numerous commits ago. I have had success running it for the last few months.

Comment: For the 2015 crowd reading this SO. Just use [PM2](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/nodejs/using-pm2-to-run-your-node-js-apps-like-a-pro/) instead of Forever.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

- You should really really use a framework (I recommend something like Express since it was battle-tested) unless you want to deal with sessions, cookies, middleware etc by yourself. Express is really light.
- Starting the server with nohup: you shouldn't do that, just start it with the regular "node" command. Also Express wraps the routes in a try-catch, so your server won't crash in a route. However if your server does have a serious problem, you shouldn't fear restarting it (besides, if you have 2-3 processes at least, only one will die, so there will be at least 1-2 remaining and the user won't feel a thing).
- For monitoring I personally prefer something more at the OS-level such as [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) and [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/).
- Hosting solution: since you already have your own serious hardware stuff, no need to invest money in something else. Just use a load-balancer (maybe nginx or node-http-proxy) to proxy stuff.

Answer (score 15):

See [Hosting Node Apps](https://web.archive.org/web/20170117133754/http://dailyjs.com/2010/03/15/hosting-nodejs-apps/).

> This tutorial walks you through setting up a server that can host node.js apps for server-side JavaScript applications. Right now, the node.js hosting options boil down to running node daemon processes that talk to a web server. Most web servers can proxy connections to a different port, so you’ll be able to use Apache or nginx to do this.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 6):

Try using pm2 it is simple and intuitive CLI, installable via NPM. Just start your application with PM2 and your application is ready to handle a ton of traffic

[PM2 Offical Link](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

[How to set up a node js application for production using pm2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 5):

There are three questions here, I think.

Question 0: "Should I use a framework for my node app?"

Question 1: "How do I run node servers on production machines?"

Question 2: "How do I deploy node apps to production".

For **Question 1**, I really like [Cluster](http://learnboost.github.com/cluster/) (although the latest Node version has something like that built in, so you might check that out). I've had good success with something like Monit/Upstart to monitor OS level events and make sure your servers are in good health. (This was monitoring N clusters of Ruby Thin servers, but same thing).

Depending on the traffic you may want to run cluster on multiple machines, then putting a load balancer in front of that. This depends on your traffic, how long requests take to complete / how long you block the event loop, and how many processors/node instances you launch per machine.

A framework gives you better error handling, and catches errors that would exit normal node.js apps. If you do it without a framework, make sure you read up on error handling in node.js.

For **Question 2**, I don't think the node community has a good deploy standard yet. You could try using Ruby's Capistrano tool (and here's [a blog entry talking about deploying cluster with Capinstrano](http://railsbros.de/2011/02/18/deploying_a_node_js_server_with_capistrano_and_cluster.html)).

The bad thing about Capistrano is that it makes some assumptions that might not be true (ie: that you're deploying a Rails project), so you may end up fighting with the framework a lot.

My goto deployment solution in general is Python's [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.3/index.html) tool, which gives you deployment tools and lets you do what you need to do.

Another deployment option is "the cloud", with things like [Nodester](http://nodester.com/): let them take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

You might get better answers over on ServerFault, but there's a description of [one user's experience here](http://cuppster.com/2011/05/12/diy-node-js-server-on-amazon-ec2/) using [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org/). You're going to need to use some sort of process watcher to keep the `node` process alive, and another common recommendation seems to be to reverse-proxy connections to the `node` process somehow. I'd probably vote for `nginx` (this way you can have `nginx` handle the logging, authentication, or any other higher-level HTTP features you need as opposed to somehow baking them into node), but the aforementioned article mentions `haproxy` in the comments here and there which may be more lightweight. Your choice of reverse-proxy will probably depend largely on whether or not you need WebSocket support.

I'm not sure any more "standard" workflow exists for node just yet; it's not quite as mature as something like Rails that has a myriad of ways to keep a webapp running.

Answer (score 0):

The guys at Cloudkick wrote an an excellent solution to this. It's called `Cast`, http://cast-project.org/.

Install cast on your server and on your workstation. You start the cast-agent on the server and have your workstation sign with the servers cast instance. You can then create "bundles", upload them to the server, create/upgrade/destroy from them as well as start/stop the your instances. Cast will automatically restart your services when they crash. You can also tail the stdout/strerr remotely as well as get a list of running instances and PID#s and manage your instances/servers from your workstation (no SSHing required). The docs are slightly out of date, but the results are worth the little bit of extra work. All of the interactions/commands are over HTTPS and a RESTful API.

Prior to this I was doing all the upgrades by hand with SCP/SSH. We has `supervise` keeping things up. We haven't looked back.

Comment: It's dead, Jim! The website is now full of seo-garbage and Google does not find anything interesting for "node.js cast"

Comment: Yup, it's abandon. We are maintaining an in-house version atm. The repo can be found where: https://github.com/cloudkick/cast