# Yeoman angular dist version of app, does not restrict the direct folder access

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, gruntjs, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I am facing this issue for my angular app.

Dist version of app, does not restrict the direct folder access.

so www.mysite.com/scripts and  /images  and /styles folder are accessible.

This issue is not coming in development i.e. grunt serve
this is coming in grunt serve:dist.

I have tried the deny folder using .htaccess of dist folder. but doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.htaccess` files are specific for apache server, but you are running grunt, so all .htaccess files are ignored.

You should not use Grunt as your production server, since it is designed to local development environment only.

Take a look here:
[can grunt server use for production application deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577336/can-grunt-server-use-for-production-application-deployment)

Files generated with grunt (in dist folder) can be copied without issues to any other sever, designed to serve files in production (nginx or apache).

Comment: Yeah, 
Thanks for the guidance, I will use express for production server.